# How to set connection string in C# project?

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to SQL Server and C#.

I installed the database on one computer and installed my simple Windows application on another computer. Now I want to set connection string in the `application.exe.config` file.

I searched the internet and found this connection string sample:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Should I set username and password of computer to this connection string or what?

Thank you

Comment: The Username and Password is the `LOGIN` name and it's Password for the SQL Login you are using to connect to the instance.

Comment: If you are new to it, then I suggest having the server on the computer you are working and set the connection string to use "Windows Authentication". ie: @"server=.\SQLExpress;Database=myDatabase;Trusted_Connection=yes". Configuring for remote access may not be as easy as 1,2,3 at all times. For example, the port you need to access is not guaranteed to be 1433 or SQL be configured to allow remote connections, firewall configuration is not set vice versa.

Comment: See the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) for connection string keywords and examples.

Comment: you have to set server ip and and sql username and  sql password

Comment: Depends if you use SQL Authentication or Windows Authentication. The former uses a username and password (not the Windows one) the latter does not, it just uses whoever is currently logged in on the workstation